# Using rasterio and matplotlib to visualize Sentinel-1 data

Tags: rasterio, visualisation, sentinel-1

I'm trying to work with satellite data for the first time and running into problems. I find the documentation about using Sentinel-1 data in Python lacking, but maybe I'm searching for the wrong things.

I have downloaded a Sentinel-1 granule from the [copernicus.eu website](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus), and now I'm trying to get some usable visualization going in Python.

I started with the following small script which I've adapted from rasterio's documentation:

```
import rasterio
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

path = '/x.SAFE/measurement/y-00n.tiff
src = rasterio.open(path)
array = src.read(1)
pyplot.imshow(array, cmap='pink')
plt.show()
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: Image data of dtype complex128 cannot be converted to float
```

which stems from the fact that the values in `array` are complex.

How do I go about visualizing this data? Feel free to point me to it should I have missed some obvious documentation, but I couldn't find anything that helped me after googling this for several hours.

PS: I'm not set on using rasterio, but it seemed to be made for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention that by default Sentinel-1 data are not orthorectified, and there are some additional pre-processes to do if you downloaded SLC (complex) data.

Using higher level libraries such as [EOReader](https://github.com/sertit/eoreader) could help you to go directly to the interesting part (but you will need top download ESA SNAP software):

```py
from eoreader.reader import Reader
from eoreader.bands import VV

# Open the Sentinel-1 product
prod = Reader().open("S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20191215T060906_20191215T060931_030355_0378F7_3696.zip")

# Load VV band
vv_band = prod.load(VV)[VV]

# Use xarray backend to plot (or hvplot if you want)
vv_band.plot()
```

[image: s1_viz]

> Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of EOReader.

Comment: Hi, in my case I have already done some preprocessing on SNAP, gave me either a .dim or .tif files; can I still use eoreader in that case? Or only on the original .zip file?

Comment: You can still use EOReader, but with the Custom stack handler: https://eoreader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom.html. See also the notebook about this topic: https://eoreader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/custom.html